# How to remove leading zeroes & trailing spaces in COBOL

Tags: file, dataset, cobol, mainframe, flat

Hi I have requirement to read a input file, each record contains certain record

```
01 FILE-DATA.
   05 FILE-FIELD-A     PIC 9(18).
   05 FILLER           PIC X(01) VALUE '*'.
   05 FILE-FILED-B     PIC X(30).
   05 FILLER           PIC X(01) VALUE '*'.
```

input data: 12345*ACBDE12345

when I unstring the file record, each file is getting 000000012345 (leading zeroes) & 'ABCDE12345          ' (trailing spaces).

Strangely the file data is send with such variable length into to fixed data structure, to tackle this how can I go about removing the leading zeroes and Trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For leading zeroes: use COBOL editing

```
 77 FILE-FIELD-EDITED  PIC Z(17)9.

MOVE FILE-FIELD-A TO FILE-FIELD-EDITED
```

To remove trailing spaces (or possibly leading ones on the `FILE-FIELD-EDITED` var): use the instrinsic `TRIM` function:

```
STRING FUNCTION TRIM (FILE-FIELD-EDITED LEADING)
       '*'
       FUNCTION TRIM (FILE-FIELD-B TRAILING)
       DELIMITED BY SIZE
       INTO SOME-OUTPUT-FIELD
END-STRING
```

which would then  give the output you've shown above.

To learn more about editing and intrinsic functions see your COBOL implementation's language reference (that implementation may not have the `LEADING` and `TRAILING` option, for example) or for general COBOL the [current COBOL draft standard](https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19468956).

Comment: Thanks Simon, how does the FUNCTION TRIM know what is to be trimmed is it Leading zeroes or spaces?

Comment: By default it only removes spaces. But in the sample I gave the numeric field is first `MOVE`d to an edited field which replaces leading zeroes by spaces ( `Z` is zero-suppression) and then `TRIM`s that field.
The linked draft standard has the details, currently under "15.96 TRIM function" (which also allows another character to be trimmed), but I think there aren't much implementations that support this already.